# Task :webpack FAILED , Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, jhipster

Am facing errors while building a jhipster project by executing `./gradlew` in a the project's directory.

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :webpack

> oauth-2@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack:build /home/lina/PCD/app
> npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:build:main


> oauth-2@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT cleanup /home/lina/PCD/app
> rimraf build/resources/main/static/ build/resources/main/aot


> oauth-2@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack:build:main /home/lina/PCD/app
> npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --env.stats=minimal


> oauth-2@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack /home/lina/PCD/app
> node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.dev.js" "--env.stats=minimal"

Webpack: Starting ...
Starting type checking service...
Webpack: Starting ...

   ✔ Compile modules
   ✔ Build modules
   ✔ Optimize modules
   ✔ Emit files

Webpack: Finished after 29.312 seconds.

ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors3:54:41 PM

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Thread Loader (Worker 0)
Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at PoolWorker.fromErrorObj (/home/lina/PCD/app/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:262:12)
    at /home/lina/PCD/app/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:204:29
    at mapSeries (/home/lina/PCD/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3625:14)
    at PoolWorker.onWorkerMessage (/home/lina/PCD/app/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:170:35)
    at Linter.parseResults (/home/lina/PCD/app/node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/Linter.js:121:13)
    at Linter.printOutput (/home/lina/PCD/app/node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/Linter.js:85:26)
    at Object.loader (/home/lina/PCD/app/node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/index.js:26:10)

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Thread Loader (Worker 1)
Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at PoolWorker.fromErrorObj (/home/lina/PCD/app/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:262:12)
    at /home/lina/PCD/app/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:204:29
    at mapSeries (/home/lina/PCD/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3625:14)
    at PoolWorker.onWorkerMessage (/home/lina/PCD/app/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:170:35)
    at Linter.parseResults (/home/lina/PCD/app/node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/Linter.js:121:13)
    at Linter.printOutput (/home/lina/PCD/app/node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/Linter.js:85:26)
    at Object.loader (/home/lina/PCD/app/node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/index.js:26:10)
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! oauth-2@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.dev.js" "--env.stats=minimal"`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the oauth-2@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/lina/.npm/_logs/2019-12-19T00_33_28_433Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! oauth-2@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack:build:main: `npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --env.stats=minimal`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the oauth-2@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack:build:main script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/lina/.npm/_logs/2019-12-19T00_33_29_033Z-debug.log

> Task :webpack FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

these are some details may be useful : 
**Environment and Tools**
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-8u232-b09-1~deb9u1-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
- git version 2.11.0
- node: v12.13.1
- npm: 6.13.4
- yeoman: 3.1.1

Am running it on Debian 9 (stretch) 
Any help would be appreciated , thank you.

Comment: Have you tried running it on node 10.x ? Can you paste the lines before `ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors12:41:18 AM` ?

Comment: No I didn't , my node version is  v12.13.1 , I edited the post and added the lines you asked for :)

Comment: Could you try running `./gradlew -PnodeInstall`? It does install node locally in your project and uses it for building in isolation from the node version you have installed on your PC.

Comment: I got the same error

Comment: I answered you on github, it was easier to post some code https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/10619

Comment: thank you for your help ,; that solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Gaël Marziou

> Failure is about eslint, so I suppose it also fails when you run npm
>   run lint? As a temporary workaround and to confirm there's an issue
>   with eslint could you comment out the eslint-loader rule configuration
>   in webpack/webpack.dev.js like below?

```
module: {
    rules: [ /* {
        test: /\.(j|t)s$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
    }, */
```